# Handle Django MIgrations

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm working on a Django project with Postgres database using Docker. We are facing some issues in with our migrations, I did not add Django migrations inside .gitignore because I want everyone to have the same database fields and same migrations as well, but every time when someone changes the models or add a new model and push the code with migrations so migrations re not applying in our database as it should be, every time we faced this issue that sometimes ABC key doesn't exist or ABC table doesn't exist, so how can I overcome from it.

Dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 8000

COPY ./core/ /app/
COPY ./scripts /scripts

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt && \
    adduser --disabled-password --no-create-home app && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/static && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/media && \
    chown -R app:app /vol && \
    chmod -R 755 /vol && \
    chmod -R +x /scripts

USER app

CMD ["/scripts/run.sh"]
```

run.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

ls -la /vol/
ls -la /vol/web

whoami

python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate

uwsgi --socket :9000 --workers 4 --master --enable-threads --module myApp.wsgi
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
   
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: "postgres"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - dev.env
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=POSTGRES_DB
      - POSTGRES_USER=POSTGRES_USER
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=POSTGRES_PASSWORD

  app:
    container_name: app
    build: 
      context: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./core:/app
      - ./data/web:/vol/web
    env_file:
      - dev.env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Comment: The `command:` override in the `docker-compose.yml` runs instead of the `CMD` in the Dockerfile, which means you're script isn't getting run.  The first `volumes:` line beneath it also replaces the application code in the image with whatever random thing is on the host, which can be another source of inconsistency between systems.  You should be able to delete both of these lines.

Comment: @DavidMaze can you attach an example?